# Check if user finished sliding on a continuous UISlider?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my app, I have a couple of UISlider instances to change various values. The values are displayed right next to the slider, as well as rendered in a 3d space in another visible part of the app.

The 3d part includes some rather heavy calculations, and right now it doesn't seem possible to update it live as the slider changes. That would imply that I'd have to set the slider's `continuous` property to `NO`, therefore only getting updates when the slider has finished changing.

I'd prefer to have the *displayed* value update live, however. Is there a way to have a slider that is continuous (so I can update my value-label in real time) and still sends some kind of message once the user has finished interacting with it? My gut feeling right now is to subclass UISlider and override the `touchesEnded:` method. Is that feasible?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can do this with simple target/actions.

Set a target and action for the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event, and then another target and action for the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event. With the `continuous` property set to `YES`, the value changed event will fire as the slider changes value, while the touch up inside event will only fire when the user releases the control.

Comment: doesnt work anymore on iOS7, all of a sudden. 6 is still functional.

Comment: @Jas, dont have sufficient test cases for a bugreport. I think its default iOS7 behaviour. As a quick dirty fix, I manually firing UIControlEventValueChanged/Up/Down inside a UISlider subclass.

Comment: Was running into the same issue where this stopped working in iOS7. Fixed it by adding UIControlEventTouchCancel

Comment: Works for me in iOS 8. If it ever stops working I'll try what @manggit did.

Comment: If the user touches the slide and moves his finger away from it, `touchUpInside` is never called. The Slider, however, only takes into consideration the X position of the finger, even if Y is now very far.
In this case, UIControlEventTouchCancel isn't called either.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this other than just creating a BOOL that becomes TRUE during a `UIControlEventTouchCancel` and becomes FALSE when a `touchupoutside` or `touchupinside` happens?

Comment: To answer my own question, there's no need for a bool. TouchUpOutside will only happens if the touch hapenned inside in the first place.

Comment: To @HSNN and others, indeed you can implement both `touchUpInside` and  `touchUpOutside` and call your code in it, **but** I find it more **elegant** to set the `continuous` property to NO and implement valueChanged which will only be called once the user releases his finger (outside or inside the slider).

Comment: @MichaelPirotte that depends on the situation.. You probably don't want your users to guestimate where the 35% mark is and only update the display once they made their guess...

Comment: This won't work if the user is using some other input method.  Is there an accessible way of doing this?

Answer (score 17):

I just had to do this, so I looked up touch properties, and used the full IBAction header.

This should be a viable alternative for people who want some extra control, though Jas's is definitely easier on the code side.

```
- (IBAction)itemSlider:(UISlider *)itemSlider withEvent:(UIEvent*)e;
{
    UITouch * touch = [e.allTouches anyObject];

    if( touch.phase != UITouchPhaseMoved && touch.phase != UITouchPhaseBegan)
    {
       //The user hasn't ended using the slider yet.
    }

}
```

:D

Comment: tested on iOS 5 and on iOS 7, works well in both cases. I can't believe I didn't know there's also an event parameter being sent.

Comment: @user2545330 `[slider addTarget:@selector(itemSlider:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` - this will call the method above when slider value changes. More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Comment: Note that if you do this in the Xib, you don't need to add any code besides what's in the answer. These comments make me think some coders might not read the manuals.

Comment: [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(itemSlider:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

Comment: This question keeps getting up voted, so I want to be extra clear you only need alexi and jose's code if you don't, super-easily, ctrl-drag from the slider to the file's owner in the xib. Unless it is an isolated custom view, that code isn't necessary. If you don't know how to work with Xibs, you are missing out on much unneeded code.

Answer (score 16):

Also note you should connect the `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` event as well in case the user drags his finger out of the control before lifting it.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 3:

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ slider: UISlider, _ event: UIEvent) {
    guard let touch = event.allTouches?.first, touch.phase != .ended else {
        // ended
        return
    }
    // not ended yet
}
```